# extracting street name using reverse geocoding (Google API)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

i'm using Google reverse geocoding to get the user's current location. my code goes like this:

```
    NSString* StrCurrentLongitude=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]; // string value

    NSString* StrCurrentLatitude=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%@,%@&sensor=true_or_false",StrCurrentLatitude,StrCurrentLongitude]];
```

now how do i continue from here to get the user's current location?

Answer (score 1):

of the top of my head:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithUrl:yourURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completion:^(NSURLResponse *r, NSData *d, NSError *e) {
    //decode it
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:d options:0 error:nil]; 

    //process google response, which is JSON IIRC
}];
```

Comment: is NSURLResponse  or NSData is the JSON file that i'll be receiving? and how can i extract the address (or parse?) ?

Comment: oh and the one i can use has a "queue" between the request and the completionHandler, what value do i put in it?

Comment: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] -- the NSData has the JSON